# APACHE_PID_FILE needs to be defined... Can't restart apache

Tags: apache

I followed the steps in the comment at the bottom of [this php image upload question](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/image-upload-functionality-not-working-on-my-droplet) as (stupidly) root and now I can't restart my apache server. Step (6) '`echo umask 002 >> /etc/apache2/envvars`' ruined it.

I have tried `sudo apt-get -o DPkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" --reinstall install apache2` thinking it would restore any configuration files but that fails on restarting as well.

I would rather avoid reinstalling apache, is there anything I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit /etc/apache2/bin/envvars and set the required variables?

```
# Since there is no sane way to get the parsed apache2 config in scripts, some
# settings are defined via environment variables and then used in apache2ctl,
# /etc/init.d/apache2, /etc/logrotate.d/apache2, etc.
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
# temporary state file location. This might be changed to /run in Wheezy+1
export APACHE_PID_FILE=/var/run/apache2/apache2$SUFFIX.pid
export APACHE_RUN_DIR=/var/run/apache2$SUFFIX
export APACHE_LOCK_DIR=/var/lock/apache2$SUFFIX
# Only /var/log/apache2 is handled by /etc/logrotate.d/apache2.
export APACHE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/apache2$SUFFIX

## The locale used by some modules like mod_dav
export LANG=C
## Uncomment the following line to use the system default locale instead:
#. /etc/default/locale

export LANG
```

Comment: thanks, pasting in your contents of the envvars file fixed it :)